# how do i display c++ header files inside directories in visual studio

Tags: c++, user-interface, visual-studio-2013, header-files

My project has about twenty header files, and it's starting to become a bind to search through the header files to find the header file I want. I have the classes namespaced, and each namespace is essentially a directory.  How can I view the header files organised in the directories or namespaces in visual studio 2013 instead of one long list?

Comment: 20 is nothing.  Try 2000.

Comment: @JohnDibling I'll raise your 2000 to 14,248

Comment: 20 is more impressive than 14,248 to me.

Comment: I wish it was as low as 20 :(, filtering is your only option, otherwise you have to create new virtual folders in the project space and drag the header files to that folder. Otherwise you have to do a `ctrl+shift+f` to search the universe or use a tool like VisualAssist or similar to help with file finding

Comment: In the C# world, visual studio is an amazing IDE. As a C++ editor, it feels incredibly basic and limited.

Comment: @user3791372: Tone it down.

Comment: @user3791372 I've found Visual Assist really helps make MSVC a lot more usable, particularly with refactoring.  It costs money though.

Comment: Supposedly the latest visual studios have better intellisense but can't say as I'm stuck on VS 2008

Comment: The reason I say that is that I remember reading that they rewrote it for VS 2010 so I would expect it to be much faster but I have no first-hand experience of this

Comment: There were big changes in the C# editor of vs 2012 iirc. But by comparison, c++ editor feels ten years behind

Comment: visual assist looks handy, like a basic resharper of the c++ world. I am saddened that I couldn't find an addon to display the files in namespaces / directories - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the project and select `Add\New Filter`

Enter the name you want and drag the header files into the filter.  They won't be put into folders on the file system though (as that would break the `#include` statements)

Comment: Can't this be done automatically? As the project grows and the directory count grows, having to manually create a filter is a pita I don't want!

Comment: @user3791372 No, I'm afraid not :(

Comment: Gah! It's a solution, not the answer I wanted nor will probably use, but it fixes the problem I guess.

Answer (score -1):

It isn't a perfect solution, but the class view shows the classes as a namespaced list, which allows for better grouping of classes than the solution view.